# Using py2neo to get nodes with second order connections?

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

How can [py2neo `RelationshipMatcher`](https://py2neo.org/v4/matching.html#py2neo.matching.RelationshipMatcher) or similar be used to return all nodes with a second order connection to an original node?

I can use the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (u)-[:has]-()-[:validates]-(result)
WHERE u.UserName = "Dave" 
RETURN result
```

Which with the below graph would give me routes A, B and C

---

[Graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0LaY.png)

However, using `db.evaluate(query` (as below) with the same query only returns the first matching node (i.e. `Route A`)

```py
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship, NodeMatcher, RelationshipMatcher

def get_routes(username):
    query = "MATCH (u)-[:has]-()-[:validates]-(result) WHERE u.UserName = '"'{}'"' RETURN result".format(username)
    result = db.evaluate(query)

db = Graph("bolt://X.X.X.X:7687", username = "neo4j", password = "password")
get_routes("Dave")
```

Something like below would return the first order nodes connected to my user (i.e. `Condition1`, `Condition2`).

How can I amend this code to deliver the matching 2nd order nodes?

```py
u = db.nodes.match("User", UserName=username).first()
matcher = RelationshipMatcher(db)
nodes = matcher.match((u, None), "has")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52734369)

`result = db.run(query).data()` instead of `result = db.evaluate(query)`

This returns a dictionary of matching nodes